# How to implement user login and posting to multiple social media platforms using Passport.js or Auth0 with specific permissions?

Tags: node.js, passport.js, auth0, social-media

I am working on a web application that requires users to log in using their social media accounts (Instagram, Facebook, LinkedIn, etc.) and then post content to these platforms on behalf of the users. I am considering using either Passport.js or Auth0 for authentication, but I'm unsure how to handle the login process and obtain the necessary permissions.

Can someone provide an example or guidance on how to implement this functionality using Passport.js or Auth0? Specifically, I need to ensure that during the login process, the user grants specific permissions to our application to allow posting on their behalf.

Any code examples, tutorials, or recommended libraries would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

I anticipated finding comprehensive examples or documentation that would guide me in incorporating the necessary permissions during the login process. Ideally, I wanted to obtain user consent for posting on their behalf and securely store the required access tokens for future use.